# How to insert multiple data into a table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I have a table and every row items have an addtocart button each and when i click the addtocart button, a modal shows and it has ok button for the qty that i want to order, when i click ok button another modal will show and it has the table form like the first table and it shows the items that i ordered, and when I click the ok button, I want that rows to be inserted on the database.

```
$( $table ).delegate(".Addtocart", "click", function() {
                var itemNo = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.itemNo').html();
                var selected_item = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.itemdescr').html();
                var remaining_qty = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.currqty').html();
                var unitPrice = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.unit_price').html();
                var amount = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.Amount').html();
                $("#action").val('add');
                $('#itemNo').val(itemNo);
                $('#selected_item').val($.trim(selected_item));
                $('#remaining_qty').val(remaining_qty);
                $('#unitPrice').val(unitPrice);
                $('#amount').val(amount);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
```

heres the 2nd ok button for the 2nd modal

```
$('#OKBtn2').click(function(){
            $('#myModal2').modal('hide');
            var itemid = $('#main-form2 .active').attr('id'),
                qty = $('#main-form2 #'+itemid+' td:eq(2)').text(),
                amount = $('#main-form2 #'+itemid+' td:eq(4)').text();
                bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?","No","Yes",function(r){
                    if(r) {
                        var itemno = $('#itemNo').val();
//                        var currqty = $('#orderqty').val();
                        var unit_price = $('#unitPrice').val();
//                        var Amount = $('#amount').val();
                        $.ajax({  
                            url : url,
                            type : "POST",
                            async : false,
                            data : {
                                    Modify: 1,
                                    Delete:1,
                                    Add: 1,
                                    itemNo: itemno,
                                    orderqty: qty,
                                    unit_price: unit_price,
                                    amount: amount,
                                    todo:"Add"
                                       },
                        success:function(result){
                        bootbox.alert('Ordered',function(){
                        });
                        updateTable();
                        }
                    });

                    } else {

                    }
                });
            });
```

how can I convert this into an array? The data inserts to the table but it inserts the row item that is selected or highlighted only, it doesn't inserts the other row items. the row has class that when you click it highlights the row.

```
case "Add":
        if(isset($_POST['Add'])){
                    $Addquery = "INSERT INTO tb_empgrocery (empgrocID, coopmemID , date_ordered, item_no, qty_ordered, unit_price, amount, date_delivered, qty_delivered, order_status, released_by) VALUES ('".$_POST['empgrocID']."', '".$login['is_coopmemID_kiosk']."', (NOW()), '".$_POST['itemNo']."', '".$_POST['orderqty']."', '".$_POST['unit_price']."', '".$_POST['amount']."', '".$_POST['date_delivered']."', '".$_POST['qty_delivered']."','".$_POST['order_status']."','".$_POST['released_by']."')";
                    mysql_query($Addquery, $con);
                    }
        break;
```

is this correct?

```
case "Add":
            $_POST = array_map('addlashes', $_POST);
            $values = array();
                foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                    $values[] = "('{$_POST['empgrocID']}', '{$login['is_coopmemID_kiosk']}', '{$_POST['(NOW())']}', '{$_POST['itemNo']}', '{$_POST['orderqty']}', '{$_POST['unit_price']}', '{$_POST['amount']}', '{$_POST['date_delivered']}', '{$_POST['qty_delivered']}', '{$_POST['order_status']}', '{$_POST['released_by']}')";
                }
                if(sizeof($values)) {
                    $query = "INSERT INTO tb_empgrocery (empgrocID, coopmemID , date_ordered, item_no, qty_ordered, unit_price, amount, date_delivered, qty_delivered, order_status, released_by) VALUES ".implode(',', $values);
                    $result = mysql_query($query, $con);
                }
        break;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please help Thank you

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is an array itself, you can insert data in your table as long as the post data keys match your table columns.

Comment: My code works in $_POST but I want to Insert all row items that I added in my cart list because it only inserts the rows that is selected. It won't add all  rows by clicking ok

Comment: a batch insert, you would want to create an object for each item  in the cart and push the object into an array then pass the array to your ajax request.