# How to limit Addtocart button to be only clicked once per item or disabled after clicking it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a table and has rows that have an addtocart button per row/item

```
        $( $table ).delegate(".Addtocart", "click", function() {
            var itemNo = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.itemNo').html();
            var selected_item = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.itemdescr').html();
            var remaining_qty = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.currqty').html();
            var unitPrice = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.unit_price').html();
            var amount = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.Amount').html();
            $("#action").val('add');
            $('#itemNo').val(itemNo);
            $('#selected_item').val($.trim(selected_item));
            $('#remaining_qty').val(remaining_qty);
            $('#unitPrice').val(unitPrice);
            $('#amount').val(amount);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
```

I want to disable that button on that item after i added it on my Cart List

for example:

Vinegar Addtocart
Sugar Addtocart
Salt Addtocart

Now I want to add vinegar in my cart list. After I added the vinegar, the addtocart button on that vinegar has been disabled. How? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you hide the button after clicking it...

Another option is to use a class based filter like

```
$($table).delegate(".Addtocart:not(.clicked)", "click", function () {
    var itemNo = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.itemNo').html();
    var selected_item = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.itemdescr').html();
    var remaining_qty = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.currqty').html();
    var unitPrice = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.unit_price').html();
    var amount = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.Amount').html();
    $("#action").val('add');
    $('#itemNo').val(itemNo);
    $('#selected_item').val($.trim(selected_item));
    $('#remaining_qty').val(remaining_qty);
    $('#unitPrice').val(unitPrice);
    $('#amount').val(amount);
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $(this).addClass('clicked')
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I'm very new in programming that's why I ask for help. Thank you

Comment: Can you help me on my other question? Thank you   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086243/how-to-insert-data-into-a-table-using-php-array/32087597#32087597

Comment: @MicaelaMingYamato havent used PHP much :(

Comment: No problem :) Thank youuu :)

Comment: can you help me here please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518022/changing-tds-background-color-to-success-or-danger/32518163#32518163

Comment: Yes but that's not what exactly I wanted to do because when I refesh the page, the background color's gone

Comment: @Micaela in that you need to remember the last state... you can either use cookies or web storage to do that