# Changing td's background color to success or danger

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Here is my php where I want this td (`order_status`) change background color to `green or success` if the order was `delivered` and to change background color as `danger or red` if the order was `canceled`.

```
<?php
    if(!session_id()){
        session_start();
    }
    include_once '../fileadmin/dbinit.php';
    $todo = $_POST['todo'];
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","","atec_coop");
    if (!$con){
        die("Can't connect".mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("atec_coop",$con);
    switch ($todo) {
        case "display":
            $sql = "SELECT * from tb_empgroc_master";
            $result = $atecCoop->query($sql);

            $html = ''; $ctr = 0;
            if ($result->num_rows){
                while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
                $id = $row->empgrocmstID;
                $date_ordered = date("m-d-Y");
                $order_no = date($row->order_no);
                $total_items = number_format($row->total_items);
                $total_amount = number_format($row->total_amount,2);
                $order_status = wordwrap($row->order_status);

                $html .= "<tr id='$id'>";
                $html .= "<td class='date_ordered' style='text-align:center'>$date_ordered</td>";
                $html .= "<td class='order_no' style='text-align:center'>$order_no</td>";
                $html .= "<td class='total_items' style='text-align:right'>$total_items</td>";
                $html .= "<td class='total_amount' style='text-align:right'>$total_amount</td>";
                $html .= "<td class='order_status' style='text-align:center'>$order_status</td>";
                $html .= "</tr>";
                }
            }
            echo $html;
        break;
        case "Cancel":
            $Cancelquery = "UPDATE tb_empgroc_master SET order_status='Cancelled' WHERE empgrocmstID='".$_POST['empgrocmstID']."'";
            mysql_query($Cancelquery, $con);
        break;
        case "Approve":
            $Approvequery = "UPDATE tb_empgroc_master SET order_status='Delivered' WHERE empgrocmstID='".$_POST['empgrocmstID']."'";
            mysql_query($Approvequery, $con);
        break;
    }
?>
```

Here's my table form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="main-form" action="PHP_groceryReleasingProcess.php" method="POST">
    <table class="tablesorter table table-bordered table-condensed" id="cLoanOut" style="table-layout: fixed;">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="110">
            <col width="130">
            <col width="50">
            <col width="60">
            <col width="90">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date Ordered</th>
                <th>Order No.</th>
                <th>Total Item(s)</th>
                <th>Total Amount</th>
                <th>Order Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button id="Approve" role="button" class="btn btn-success" disabled>Approve Order</button>
    <button id="Cancel" role="button" class="btn btn-danger" disabled>Cancel Order</button>
</form>
```

And my javacript ajax call

```
$("#Approve").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $('#cLoanOut tr.active').attr('id');
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to approve order?","No","Yes",function(r){
        if(r) {
            $.ajax({  
                url : "<?php echo $server_name; ?>/emcis_coopmain/process/PHP_groceryReleasingProcess.php",
                type : "POST",
                async : false,
                data : {
                    empgrocmstID:id,
                    todo:"Approve"
                },
                success:function(result){
                    bootbox.alert('Order Approved',function(){
                    $("#Approve").attr("disabled", true);
                    });
                    updateTable();
                }
            });   
        } else {

        }
    });
});
$("#Cancel").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $('#cLoanOut tr.active').attr('id');
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel order?","No","Yes",function(r){
        if(r) {
            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo $server_name; ?>/emcis_coopmain/process/PHP_groceryReleasingProcess.php",
                type : "POST",
                async : false,
                data : {
                    empgrocmstID:id,
                    todo:"Cancel"
                },
                success:function(result){
                    bootbox.alert("Order Cancelled",function(){
                    $("#Cancel").attr("disabled", true);
                    });
                    updateTable();
                }
            });   
        } else {

        }
    });
});
```

If i clicked `Approve Order button`, the data of `order_status` which is the td (`Pending`) will change to `Delivered` and if I clicked `Cancel Order button` it will change to `Cancelled`.

If success, I want to change the `background color` of that `td` into `success/green` if the order was `approved/delivered`. If `canceled`, change `background color` to `danger/red`.

I appreciate your help thanks.

It looks like this. Every tr has an active class when you click.

```
Date Ordered         Order No.     Total item(s) Total Amount   Order Status
 09-11-2015      15-09-0000000001        3          213.85        Pending
 09-11-2015      15-09-0000000002        1          130.00       Delivered
 09-11-2015      15-09-0000000003        2          134.07        Pending
 09-11-2015      15-09-0000000004        4          846.41       Cancelled

       <button>Approve Order</button> <button>Cancel Order</button>
```

My script for the `updateTable();`

```
function updateTable(){
//                $tbody = $('#cLoanOut tbody'),
//                url = $('#main-form').attr('action');
//                $.post("PHP_groceryReleasingProcess.php",{todo:"display"},function(response){
//                    $('.progress').hide();
//                    $tbody.html(response);
//                    $table.trigger('update');
//                },'html');
    var dataString = "todo=display";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo $server_name; ?>/emcis_coopmain/process/PHP_groceryReleasingProcess.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(sg){
            $("#cLoanOut tbody").empty();
            $("#cLoanOut").find('tbody').append(sg).trigger('update');
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('.progress').hide();
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            bootbox.alert('Search Failed.');
        }
    });
}
```

I added css to my form

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.danger:hover {
     background-color: red !important;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.warning:hover {
     background-color: yellow !important;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.success:hover {
     background-color: green !important;
}
```

How can I call `success` for `Delivered` and `danger` for `Cancelled` if true to my td (`order_status`)?

Comment: Could you provide your jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: I've edited my post @WisdmLabs

Comment: @Micaela what do you have in `result` of success on both ajax?

Comment: ahm..It will update the table from pending to delivered if it was approved and canceled if it is canceled. Sorry if I didn't understand your question @Jai

Comment: @Micaela when you make the ajax call then what are you echoing from that php end. is it something like `sucess` or `cancel`.

Comment: @Jai None. That's all my php code. I'm just calling the data of order status and the update queries for the 2 buttons.

Comment: @Micaela one last question what is this doing `updateTable();`?

Comment: @Jai i'm echoing those $html's only

Comment: @Jai It Posts the todo display

Comment: var dataString = "todo=display"; @Jai

Comment: @Jai I've edited my post, you can see the `updateTable();`

Comment: @Micaela Did you try my posted answer?

Comment: Yes @Jai wait.. working on it.. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to add a specific id to `<td id="xxx">` of status order and then you can use same id in your jquery to add respective background color and change Text as "Delivered or Cancel".

You need to do this process on ajax call success event.

```
$("#xxx").css("background-color", "green");
$("#xxx").css("background-color", "red");

$("#xxx").html("Delivered");
$("#xxx").html("Cancel");
```

Comment: td's color does not change

Comment: makes error if i put id in my td. `$html .= "<td id="Order" class='order_status danger' style='text-align:center'>$order_status</td>";`

Comment: yes should use single quotes $html .= "<td id='Order' class='order_status danger' style='text-align:center'>$order_status</td>"; and if its work please take a step to accept the answer

Comment: It works but it only change the color of the first row td. If I approved another row, the first one changes

Comment: And the color blinks because of the updateTable(); but if I remove it. the color stays

Comment: if there are multiple <td> then you have to apply unique ids for all <td>, you should attache order id, if you have getting it from database <td id='Order_your respective id'>

Comment: ahm. It works now but it doesn't stay if i refresh the page. In my onclick Approve button
`$('tr.active td.order_status').css("background-color", "green");
 $('tr.active td.order_status').html("Delivered");` And in my onclick Cancel button
`$('tr.active td.order_status').css("background-color", "red");
 $('tr.active td.order_status').html("Cancelled");`

Comment: For that you need to write business logic in your php file.

Comment: Can you help me please?

Comment: You need to set a class for particular <td> as per you have set the status like "Delivered" and "Cancelled", if you are saving this status into the database then you can fetch this values from db and set to respective <td>

Answer (score 2):

Something like this in your PHP loop :

```
$html .= '<tr id="$id" class="'. ($order_status == 'cancel' ? 'cancel' : 'approved') .'">';
```

You set a class to the TR depending on the $order_status. Then in your CSS :

```
tr.cancel td {
    background: red;
}
tr.approved td {
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: the data of `order_status` was gone

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having two clicks and using same ajax you can simplify this:

```
$("#main-form button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this); // cache the clicked button here
    var id = $('#cLoanOut tr.active').attr('id');
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to "+ this.id.toLowerCase() +" order?","No","Yes",function(r){
        if(r) {
            $.ajax({  
                url : "<?php echo $server_name; ?>/emcis_coopmain/process/PHP_groceryReleasingProcess.php",
                type : "POST",
                async : false,
                data : {
                    empgrocmstID:id,
                    todo:this.id // pass the button id here Approve/Cancel
                },
                success:function(result){
                    var msg = result === "Approved" ? "Order Approved" : "Order Cancelled";
                    bootbox.alert(msg, function(){
                       $this.prop("disabled", true); // use prop 
                    });
                    updateTable();
                },
                complete:function(){
                   $('#cLoanOut tr').each(function(){
                      $(this).find('td').last().addClass(function(){
                          if(this.textContent.trim() === "Cancelled"){
                              return "danger";
                          }else if(this.textContent.trim() === "Delivered"){ 
                              return "success";
                          }
                      });
                   });
                }
            });   
        } else {

        }
    });
});
```

---

In the above snippet what i have changed:

1. Button selector within a context of your form. `$("#main-form button")` which lets you click on both buttons.
2. `var $this = $(this);` you can use to have a variable which will later be used in the callbacks like `error:fn, success:fn, complete:fn`.
3. `this.id.toLowerCase()` lets you have a dynamic popup message for both buttons.
4. `todo:this.id` we are passing the clicked button's id.
5. `var msg = result === "Approved" ? "Order Approved" : "Order Cancelled";` this line can be used for both buttons messages if you return a specific text from the php.
6. `$this.prop("disabled", true);` here `$this` is the clicked button as we cached it and use `.prop()` method to change any property like `disabled, checked etc.`.
7. Add a `complete` callback to add a class to the tds. you can see that in the snippet.

In this answer *5* is where some issue might arise for you.

Comment: Will you edit your comments and do it for me.. I've tried it but I don't know how to pass the buttons id in that `todo:this` and I dont understand the cache the clicked button here. Sorry i'm new in programming

Comment: I've tried this `todo:this.$('#Approve Cancel')` // Is this right?

Comment: @Micaela `this.id` does that you don't have to do anything explicitly.

Comment: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Comment: ^ That means that somewhere in your code, you are calling a function which in turn calls another function and so forth, until you hit the call stack limit.